# Returning a string when data list does not consist of pairs

Tags: function-construction, homework

Problem statement:

> Modify your function to return the string "Not a list of ordered
>   pairs!" if the list isn't a list of ordered pairs, otherwise return
>   the same mean as problem 5e.  (Don't forget to try all of the cases
>   shown below - each of these checks for a different potential bug.)
>
> Here are examples of how it should look:
>
> function5f[{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}},3,7]
>
> Not a list of ordered pairs!
>
> function5f[{{11,3},{3,8}, {4,7}, {6,2}, {7,4},{10,6}},3,7]
>
> 5.25

So far I have this:

```
function6[pairs_, min_,max_] :=(
   If[min <= #[[1]] <= max, 
   Return["Not a list of ordered pairs!"]]; 
   Return["In the list of ordered pairs!"]
)
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `MatchQ[{{_, _} ...}]` to test whether the list is a list of pairs or not. I'm not sure based on the description why it matters whether the pairs are ordered or not, perhaps that is explained elsewhere. You have introduced parameters `min` and `max` which I also don't see why they matter based on the description, so I assume that there is more.

Comment: I think they wanted us to use "If" statements

Comment: @Moth I think perhaps you will want to give this some tries before looking for external help on your homework.

Comment: In your `function6`, neither the `( )` nor `Return` is needed.